# Merge fraction with x in it

Tags: linear-algebra, fractions

I have a problem. My teacher made an online explanation about merging fractions. She wrote the following:
$$\frac{1}{x+1}+3$$
Then she wanted that to merge in one fraction, so she did this:
$$\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{3(x+1)}{(x+1)}=\frac{1+3x+3}{x+1}=\frac{3x+4}{x+1}$$

Now I understand why she does this, but calculating with $1$ is easy. In my case I have $24$ like this:
$$\frac{24}{x+2}+4$$

How do I write this in one fraction?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: The $24$ doesn’t change anything, just multiply the $4$ by $\frac{x+2}{x+2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y=\frac{24}{x+2}+4=\frac{24+4\cdot(x+2)}{x+2}=\frac{24+4x+8}{x+2}=\frac{4x+32}{x+2}$$

Please take in consideration to see some basic LaTeX commands.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk: Click the accept button to mark it as accepted so that it doesn't unnecessarily bother users who want to help.